# $\tilde H_n(X\cup CA)\to\tilde H_n(SA)$ is compatible with long exact sequence for $(X,A)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $(X,A)$ be a pair of spaces, $CA,SA$ be the cone, suspension of $A$, respectively. I want to show the map $\tilde H_n(X\cup CA)\to\tilde H_n(SA)$ induced by the quotient map is compactible with the boundary map $H_n(X,A)\to\tilde H_{n-1}(A)$ in the long exact sequence for $(X,A)$, under the natural identifications.

Explicitly, this reduces to checking the commutativity of the following diagram (which I cannot quite figure out):
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H_n(X,A) @>\cong>> H_n(X\cup CA,CA) @<\cong<<\tilde H_n(X\cup CA)\\
@VVV @. @VVV \\
\tilde H_{n-1}(A) @<\cong<< H_n(CA,A) @>\cong>> H_n(X\cup CA,X).
\end{CD}
$$